# Authentication with FireBase using email id and password: Unable to Merge Dex

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-multidex

I found something new while doing research on **firebase authentication** functionality for my project. After enabling email and password type and using the given below library of firebase it shows me the error of **unable to merge dex**. Whenever I use this library I get this error.

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.0'
```

Is this library is not compatible with the latest version of the android studio?

Here is my gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "htl.com.googlemaps"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                includeCompileClasspath true
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.2'
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.2"
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I also attached the image of error on this issue.

[image]

Comment: share your **`Build.Gradle`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting

> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge
>   dex

```
  FirebaseUI Version    Firebase/Play Services Version
    3.1.2                   11.6.2
    3.1.0                   11.4.2
    3.0.0                   11.4.2
    2.4.0                   11.4.0
```

If you use [**`'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.0'`**](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android), Make sure your respective **`Firebase/Play`** version is **`11.4.2`**.

**Example**

```
com.google.android.gms:play***:11.4.2
com.google.firebase:firebase***:11.4.2
```

Comment: I shared the gradle in my question.

Comment: @Dnveeraj `compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0'`

Comment: @Dnveeraj After that, `Clean-Rebuild-Run`

Comment: @Dnveeraj Solved this yet?

Comment: Your solution sloved my issue,Yes that was the problem with the defferent version in my gradle.